Renaming varibles from key:value pair in R
I am working with some publicly available employment data from the BEA (CAINC4 from this page: https://apps.bea.gov/regional/downloadzip.cfm). I reshaped the data to calculate employment rates, but the variable names are pretty messy. I tried to write a function to rename them based on key:value pairs, but have not had any success.
library(ggplot2)
library(usmap)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(cowplot)
library(plotly)


 inc_rr = structure(list(fips = c("01001", "01003", "01005", "01007", "01009", 
"01011"), geoname = c("Autauga, AL", "Baldwin, AL", "Barbour, AL", 
"Bibb, AL", "Blount, AL", "Bullock, AL"), region = c(5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), tablename = c("CAINC4", "CAINC4", "CAINC4", 
"CAINC4", "CAINC4", "CAINC4"), x1969_10 = c(69973, 157191, 51130, 
29810, 69322, 22716), x1969_20 = c(25166, 56951, 23818, 14994, 
26411, 12554), x1969_7010 = c(6630, 20008, 9428, 4087, 7660, 
4370), x1969_7020 = c(5457, 14886, 7149, 3344, 4839, 3431), x1970_10 = c(77712, 
172745, 57657, 32551, 70070, 25439), x1970_20 = c(24606, 59474, 
22655, 13798, 26999, 11749), x1970_7010 = c(6853, 19749, 9448, 
3965, 7587, 4281), x1970_7020 = c(5650, 14713, 7323, 3259, 4891, 
3360)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

## Function for renaming data

# Write linecode dictionary
codes <- list(
  inc = 10,
  pop = 20,
  emp = 7010,
  wemp = 7020
)

codes <- list(
  "10" = "inc",
  "20" = "pop",
  "7010" = "emp",
  "7020" = "wemp"
)

rename_vars <- function(var_name) {
  var_name <- sub("^x", "", var_name)  # Remove the "x" prefix
  year <- substr(var_name, 1, 4)  # Extract the year from the variable name
  type <- substr(var_name, start = 6, stop = nchar(var_name)) # extract the line code


I am unsure which codes list to use, hence two being there. The end of the above block is as far as I get without errors. I want to write something like

rename_vars <- function(var_name) {
  var_name <- sub("^x", "", var_name)  # Remove the "x" prefix
  year <- substr(var_name, 1, 4)  # Extract the year from the variable name
  type <- substr(var_name, start = 6, stop = nchar(var_name)) # extract the line code
  if (type %in% names(codes)) {
  new_name = paste0(type, year, sep = "_")
return(new_name)
} else {
return(var_name) 
}

test <- inc_rr %>%
  rename_with(rename_vars, starts_with("x"))

but this has not worked for me -- nothing changes in the variable names.
Example of variable names in reshaped data that I want to apply this function to:
x1969_10, x1969_7020, x1980_20, etc.. Years includes are 1969-2022, and I am only using the linecodes listed in the codes list. The basic idea is to have the function remove the "x" prefix, then store the year of the variable, match the code to its key pair, and rename each variable as key_year.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your post, I suggest you give a small sample of you dataset using dput(head(inc_rr)) in order to skip the unnecessary data preprocessing for readers. Try this guide

Thanks, Derf! I've edited the post to include a sample of the data.

Your function has a few issues:

(type %in% names(codes)) this fails beacause returns a logical vector of size length(codes)
Here new_name = paste0(type, year, sep = "_") the code just pastes again the old name, besides using pasto0 instead of paste
the function needs  to be vectorized as it is.

Try this:
rename_vars <- function(var_name) {
  var_name <- sub("^x", "", var_name)  # Remove the "x" prefix
  year <- substr(var_name, 1, 4)  # Extract the year from the variable name
  type <- substr(var_name, start = 6, stop = nchar(var_name)) # extract the line code
  # use any to reduce to boolean lenght one
  if (any(type %in% names(codes))) {
    # get mathcing code from code list
    type_name <-  codes[[which(names(codes) == type)]]
    # paste it
    new_name <-  paste(type_name, year, sep = "_")
    return(new_name)
  } else {
    return(var_name) 
  }
}

Then vectorize:
vrename_vars <- Vectorize(rename_vars)

and test:
     inc_rr %>%
     rename_with(vrename_vars, starts_with("x")) %>% colnames()
 [1] "fips"      "geoname"   "region"    "tablename"
 [5] "inc_1969"  "pop_1969"  "emp_1969"  "wemp_1969"
 [9] "inc_1970"  "pop_1970"  "emp_1970"  "wemp_1970"

